# Find Internet Radio Stations

Tags: android

I am making a simple Android App to get data from internet radio stations. For now, what I do is store 5 to 6 radio station addresses in a `Vector` and then play the music from them.
However, is there a way so that I can discover these stations dynamically ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where do you get these radio stations from?

There are probably sites that list available radio stations and their urls, you can implement a html **scraper** that reads those page and fetches the urls and stores them in your vector dynamically in your app.

You can put those sites static in your app or to make it even more "dynamic" you can put your list online so whenever an app starts it reads your list of websites where it should search for radio stations.

But what do you actually mean by term dynamically?  ----You will definitely need to do some work yourself. It wont be able to go to google itself, search for radio stations and play it if thats what you meant.